# jquery not loading in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code...

```
<?php
    function add_jquery() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }    
    add_action('init', 'add_jquery');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
        alert('jQuery IS NOT loaded')  
    } else {
        alert('jQuery IS loaded')
    }
</script>

<!-- Let's try loading jQuery the WRONG WAY when doing it in WordPress -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
        alert('jQuery IS NOT loaded')  
    } else {
        alert('jQuery IS loaded')
    }
</script>
```

The first alert says "jQuery IS NOT loaded" and the second says "jQuery IS loaded".
Why does jQuery not load when using the first method?

Comment: where are you running this? Have you checked to see where WP is inserting the jquery script tag into the DOM in relation to where this test is running?

Comment: The above code is at the top of my plugin I am trying to author

Comment: right but where does it get inserted into the DOM? If your code is above the generated jquery tag it will do exactly as you describe since your code is not told to wait till dom ready or anything. It is executed as it is read.

Comment: Doh... My bad... I had the above code before WordPress outputted the header!  Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

where is your add_jquery function? It won't work in a wordpress template. it needs to go in functions.php or someplace where it will run before the loop.

Comment: I have it in a plugin file

Comment: is all the code in the same plugin file as it is in the question? the "right way" code is telling wordpress to enqueue jquery when the init action hook runs. if the code in your question is in the same file it won't work because you are printing javascript to the browser before the init hook runs.

Answer (score 0):

its because this line loads jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

After this line jQuery is available.

what the notes are saying this is the incorrect way to load jQuery into wordpress. The typical "right" way is to add a call into your header.

Comment: or queue it to footer as modern web standards suggest. We try to load all js in footer nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

If you enqueue something in wordpress - particularly jQuery, you have to enqueue everything.  Otherwise your libraries will not have access to jQuery.